# Javascript Random Guess Game

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/andrew_jsfiddle/eyLyqajz/1/

**Assignment 1** - Using your JSFiddle account you are going to create a guessing game, only it will be the computer doing the guessing. Here is how it works - the computer will ask you for a number between 1 and 1000, it will check first to make sure your input is within the bounds.

Once you enter the number it will guess the number and do a comparison with the number you entered. It will output the results of the guess and continue to do this until it gets the correct answer. This is what the output of the program will look like (if I enter 329)

For this attempt I did:

```
    var guessnum= new Guessnum(1000);
 document.getElementById("click").onclick= function() {
 guesslist()};

 function guesslist() {
 
 document.getElementById('guessnum').innerHTML= InsertGuess();
 }


 function InsertGuess() {
 for (var a= 0; a < guessnum.length; a++){

guessnum[a] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

 }

 var show_guess="";
 for (i=0; i < guessnum.length; i++){
 show_array += "You guess" + guessnum[i] + "of " + i + "<br>";

 }

 return document.getElementById('guess').innerHTML=show_array;
 }
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 1):

Use a listener on the input with a global variable that contains the random number

```
var myRandomNumber;

input.addEventListener('input', function(){

 }
)
```

You'll need to click first on the button though.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nw6fL6uj/)

Answer (score 0):

My friend, I think you are really confused. It wouldn't help to just create it for you. Break down the requirements to actionable steps and start from scratch. You want to create a guess game that you set a number. Think it as simply as possible:

Action 1 - Set a number -->
*Create the field*

Action 2 - Check if number is valid(1-1000) -->
*Get the value entered and make the necessary checks*

*Action 3 - Computer tries to guess by selecting a num up to 1000 -->
Generate random num from 1-1000*

Action 4 - Compare number with the one you set before -->
*Simple comparison of generated number and the selected one*

Action 5 - Proceed as needed -->
*If it's the exact number it won and it will stop!

If it's higher then the next guesses should have this number as highest limit.

If it's lower then the next guesses should have this number as lowest limit.*

Action 6 - Show guess and result of comparison --> *Simply show the results of the previous actions*

Action 7 - If not successful guess --> *repeat until the number is guessed*

Try to apply this kind of logic to all these problems.